# Inserting into table from dropdown using data from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, drop-down-menu

i have a problem, I managed to list the option values for my dropdown from cms.php

```
 $query = 'SELECT * FROM categories';
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    echo "<select name='categories'>";
    echo "<option value =''>Select Category</option>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      $categories = $row['categories'];
      echo "<option value='$categories'>$categories</option>";
    }

    echo "</select>";
```

It works, the dropdown menu lists all the data from the "categories" table.
HOwever i can't insert those values from the dropdown into another table.

```
$categories = isset($_POST['categories']);
echo $categories;
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['prod_pic']['tmp_name']));
$sql="INSERT INTO `inventory` (`prod_brand`,`prod_name`,`prod_category`,`prod_price`,`prod_desc`,`prod_quantity`,`prod_pic`) 
VALUES 
('$_POST[prod_brand]','".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['prod_name'])."','{$categories}','$_POST[prod_price]',
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['prod_desc'])."','$_POST[prod_quantity]','{$image}')";
```

this just outputs 1, from the echo $categories; it also stores 1 into the database. what did i do wrong? Help please.

Comment: `$categories = isset($_POST['categories']);` to `$categories = $_POST['categories'];`

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks bro. haha. haven't figured it out on my own. maybe im tired. ahha could you post it as an aswer so i can select it as an answer? :)

Comment: You're welcome. Posted as requested.

Comment: You might want to look at 21st century coding practice, or revert to FORTRAN - your choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested.

Remove the `isset` and `()` from `$categories = isset($_POST['categories']);`

change it to `$categories = $_POST['categories'];`